# C# 'invert' list of DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I have a list of DateTimes and I need to 'invert' (for lack of a better word) this list.

```
public class Available
{
    public Available(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        if (!startDate.Day.Equals(endDate.Day))
            throw new Exception("The start and end days are not equal.");

        this.StartDate = startDate;
        this.EndDate = endDate;
    }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

List<Available> availableTimes = new List<Available>()
{
    new Available(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 08, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 10, 00, 00)),
    new Available(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 12, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 14, 00, 00)),
    new Available(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 15, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 16, 00, 00)),
};
```

I need to transform this list of available times to a list of blocked times for that particular day but I'm kind of stuck. In this case I need:

```
2015-3-16 00:00 - 2015-3-16 08:00, 
2015-3-16 10:00 - 2015-3-16 12:00, 
2015-3-16 14:00 - 2015-3-16 15:00, 
2015-3-16 16:00 - 2015-3-16 23:59
```

Any bright ideas?

Comment: The problem you are referring to is called `gaps and islands`. I put that tag into your question as well to clarify.

Comment: When is the time to be presented in the output supposed to start and end?

Comment: I've never heard of that term. Thanks.

Comment: You: `!startDate.Day.Equals(endDate.Day)` Are you aware that `.Day` gives the day-of-month number? So e.g. April **13**, 2015 and July **13**, 2017 will be the same `Day` (namely `13`). I think you meant `.Date` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, renamed your class to DateTimeRange as it has dual meanings now including blocked, and also had to make the assumption that 23:59 was midnight -1 tick.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class DateTimeRange
{
    public DateTimeRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        if (!startDate.Day.Equals(endDate.Day))
            throw new Exception("The start and end days are not equal.");

        this.StartDate = startDate;
        this.EndDate = endDate;
    }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}    



public class Program
{
    static List<DateTimeRange> availableTimes = new List<DateTimeRange>()
    {
        new DateTimeRange(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 08, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 10, 00, 00)),
        new DateTimeRange(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 12, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 14, 00, 00)),
        new DateTimeRange(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 15, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 16, 00, 00)),
    };

    private static IEnumerable<DateTimeRange> GetBlockedTimes(IEnumerable<DateTimeRange> ranges)
    {
        var min = ranges.Select(r => r.StartDate).Min().Date;
        var max = ranges.Select(r => r.EndDate).Max().AddDays(1).Date.AddTicks(-1);

        foreach(var range in ranges.OrderBy(r => r.StartDate))
        {
            yield return new DateTimeRange(min, range.StartDate);
            min = range.EndDate;
        }

        yield return new DateTimeRange(min, max);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach(var item in GetBlockedTimes(availableTimes))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.StartDate + " - " + item.EndDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list is always "sorted" and without overlapping times, the algorithm shouldn't be too hard. "Global start/end time" refers to the values `2015-3-16 00:00` and `2015-3-16 23:59` of your example.

```
start = global start time
for each item in list:
    yield new (start, item.start)
    start = item.end
yield new (start, global end time)
```

Translating it into a C# method is left as an exercise.

Comment: Plus you don't just have to assume the list is sorted, you can just make sure it is before applying the algorithm ;)

Comment: What if the first item is 0:00 - 1:00?

Comment: @Eric: Then you'll get an entry `00:00`-`00:00`. It might be easiest to just remove all "zero-length" entries afterwards. (This also applies if you have times `1:00-2:00` and `2:00-3:00`.)

Answer (score 1):

You should beware the first and end time range for marginal cases.

```
List<DateTimeRange> availableTimes = new List<DateTimeRange>()
{
    new DateTimeRange(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 1, 00, 00)),
    new DateTimeRange(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 08, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 10, 00, 00)),
    new DateTimeRange(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 12, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 14, 00, 00)),
    new DateTimeRange(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 15, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 16, 00, 00)),
    new DateTimeRange(new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 19, 00, 00), new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 23, 59, 59)),
};
var gap = GetGapsForDay(availableTimes);




public IEnumerable<DateTimeRange> GetGapsForDay(List<DateTimeRange> ranges)
{
    var start = ranges.First().StartDate.Date;
    var end = ranges.First().StartDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1);

    foreach(var item in ranges.OrderBy(i => i.StartDate))
    {
        if(start < item.StartDate)
            yield return new DateTimeRange(start, item.StartDate);

        start = item.EndDate;
    }
    if (ranges.Max(i => i.EndDate) < end)
        yield return new DateTimeRange(start, end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heinzi's algorithm turned into C#. Assumes the available intervals don't overlap and are sorted.

```
        DateTime firstDay = availableTimes[0].StartDate;
        DateTime previousTime = new DateTime(firstDay.Year, firstDay.Month, firstDay.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        List<Available> unavailableTimes = new List<Available>();

        foreach (Available available in availableTimes)
        {
            unavailableTimes.Add(new Available(previousTime, available.StartDate));
            previousTime = available.EndDate;
        }

        var dateTime = previousTime.Date;
        DateTime endDay = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, 23, 59, 59);
        unavailableTimes.Add(new Available(previousTime, endDay));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concat your `DateTime` to single dimension array:

```
        var minBorder = new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 00, 00, 00);
        var maxBorder = new DateTime(2015, 3, 16, 23, 59, 00);

        var times = new List<DateTime>();
        times.Add(minBorder);
        foreach (var at in availableTimes) {
            times.Add(at.StartDate);
            times.Add(at.EndDate);
        }
        times.Add(maxBorder);
```

result:

[image]

and then take intervals you need like this:

```
    public static IList<Available> Invert(IList<DateTime> input) {
        var result = new List<Available>();
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Count; i += 2) {
            result.Add(
                new Available(input[i], input[i + 1])
            );
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to order the list items by date, with link, this is very simple :

```
availableTimes = availableTimes.OrderByDescending(x => x.startDate).ToList();
```