# Find the gaps in a list of DateTime's all on the same day but different times

Tags: c#, list, datetime, time

I am wondering if anyone can help me, I am just learning c# and I am trying to find all the gaps (elapsed time which is not taken in the list or free time for that day) in a list of start and end date times for the same day but at different times. I can get the first and the last but not the gaps in the middle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        public class DatetimeRange
        {
            public DateTime Start { get; set; }
            public DateTime End { get; set; }
        }

        public static List<DatetimeRange> GetDateTimeGaps(List<DatetimeRange> datetimeRange, DateTime day)
        {
            var Result = new List<DatetimeRange>();

            var HighestValueOfDay = new DateTime(day.Year, day.Month, day.Day, 23, 59, 59);
            var LowestValueOfDay = new DateTime(day.Year, day.Month, day.Day, 00, 00, 00);

            var FirstStart = datetimeRange.Min(x => x.Start);
            var LastEnd = datetimeRange.Max(x => x.End);

            if (LowestValueOfDay < FirstStart)
                Result.Add(new DatetimeRange { Start = LowestValueOfDay, End = FirstStart });

            if (HighestValueOfDay > LastEnd)
                Result.Add(new DatetimeRange { Start = LastEnd, End = HighestValueOfDay });

            return Result;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            var Datetimes = new List<DatetimeRange>
            {
                new DatetimeRange { Start = new DateTime(2020, 2, 26, 12, 00, 0), End = new DateTime(2020, 2, 26, 15, 30, 0)},
                new DatetimeRange { Start = new DateTime(2020, 2, 26, 8, 30, 0), End = new DateTime(2020, 2, 26, 10, 30, 0)}
            };

            var Result = GetDateTimeGaps(Datetimes, new DateTime(2020, 2, 26, 0, 0, 0));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: By gaps I mean by elapsed time which is not taken in the list.  Sorry if my explain is not clear

Comment: @ShadowMonkey I think you need to define what your parameters are for on GetDateTimeGaps. A guess would be the day parameter specifies a single day and that the datetimeRange parameter specify times within that day and that what you're trying to do is extract another list of DatetimeRange which are the times within the specified day that are not covered by datetimeRange?

Comment: Perhaps this might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073718/c-sharp-invert-list-of-datetime

Comment: Yes @Mick I am,to extract another list of DatetimeRange which are the times within the specified day that are not covered by datetimeRange